What is the point of a write with consistency QUORUM if the consistency is not achieved?
From what I gather from this answer, if write quorum is not achieved, cassandra does not rollback the writes from the database that persisted the write.
What is the point of having a write quorum at all? How is it different from a best-effort write or sending writes to all the nodes and only waiting for one success?

There is a foundation error in your understanding. A crucial point about data replication in Cassandra is that writes are sent to ALL replicas in the cluster.
For example, a keyspace which has 3 replicas in 2 DCs, the mutation(s) in a write request are sent to ALL 6 replicas (3 replicas x 2 DCs). For the write request with consistency QUORUM to be considered successful, at least 4 (of the 6) replicas must acknowledge the write within the write request timeout.
IF not enough replicas acknowledge the write, the coordinator will reply with an UNAVAILABLE error to the client/driver. Now here is the missing piece -- the driver you're using has to make a decision on what to do next depending on how you've configured it.
For the purposes of this discussion, I'm going to use the Cassandra Java driver since it is the most popular. When a query fails, the Java driver will sometimes retry the query based on the configured retry policy. The default behaviour (DefaultRetryPolicy) for an UNAVAILABLE write error (not enough replicas acknowledged the write) is to retry the query on the next node in the query plan. If the retry fails, then you as the developer have to decide how your application will handle the failure, e.g. issue a corresponding DELETE if rollback is required by the business rules in your app.
Bottom line is that the consistency level is important since it determines whether the write request is successful or not. Without it, your app has no visibility on the state of the request and it would be impossible to determine what to do next.
If you'd like to know more about how the Cassandra Java driver handles failures, see the Retries page in the docs. Cheers!

You couldn't have explained any better. That is exactly the piece I was missing. Thanks!

Thanks for the feedback. I'm glad I nailed it. Cheers!

The point of using QUORUM for writes is to provide a guarantee, when those writes succeed, that subsequent reads with QUORUM will be consistent.
It's true that writes don't roll back, and Cassandra has mechanisms to eventually propagate writes to all replicas - hints, repairs, read repairs. However, none of these mechanisms provides a guarantee that a read query result using QUORUM will return the latest version of the data.
On the other hand, when a write with QUORUM succeeds, then a read with QUORUM for the same data will always be consistent, since at least 1 replica involved in the read request, while also involved the latest QUORUM write, returns up-to-date data. Even in the scenario where only 1 replica involved in the QUORUM read is consistent, Cassandra will resolve inconsistencies with a blocking read repair before returning results.
If you use any write consistency lower than QUORUM, even if you use QUORUM for reads, there's no guarantee that the read request will read from the replicas that succeeded in the write statement.
If alternatively you write with consistency level ALL, then you lose high availability in Cassandra - all it takes to get downtime is one unavailable node.
The formula to guarantee data consistency on reads is:
read_consistency_level + write_consistency_level > replication_factor
And usually LOCAL_QUORUM for both read and write consistency levels is the sweet spot for availability and data consistency.
I hope this helps.

I'm definitely missing something. I still don't understand the reason for a write quorum when Cassandra does not treat write requests which do not reach Quorum differently. In that case, I just don't understand the point of calling it the write Quorum. It's the same as fanning out the write requests to all replicas and only requiring one of the replica to acknowledge. I just want to understand what is handled differently when Quorum is not reached.

While the path of the mutations is the same at the database level for any write consistency level, the details lie in the dependencies for a successful write at the application level. Assuming that eventually the application is reading with QUORUM any data, if the corresponding mutations were submitted with less than QUORUM the result set can be inconsistent in the read. If the write was submitted with QUORUM, drivers and application can leverage retries to provide strong data consistency for QUORUM reads, and the result set can't be inconsistent.
